# I'd like to create a for loop that prints the square and cube alongside each number of a numeric vector

Tags: r

I'd like to create a for loop that prints the square and cube alongside each number of a numeric vector.

```
for(i in 1:15)
{
print(i^2)
}
```

This only prints the square alongside each number, how do I change this so that I can also get the cube alongside each number? I am a beginner in r and any help would be appreciated

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions and then deleting them. Please don't delete all your questions.

Comment: Thank you :) that worked

Answer (score 1):

use the `c(i, i^2, i^3)` in your print statement

this will combine all three values in a row vector